# including the current directory in a .reg script

Tags: windows, shell-scripting, windows-registry

I have a .reg script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SeleniumRC\Parameters]
"Application"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\java.exe"
"AppDirectory"="D:\\SeleniumRC"
"AppParameters"="-Xrs -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar"
```

I would like to run it from a .bat file, but rather than D:\SeleniumRC I would like to pass the current directory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

%CD% will get you your current working directory, and you may be able to use the "Reg" command rather than a .reg fragment:

http://www.petri.co.il/reg_command_in_windows_xp.htm

So, maybe something like the following would work for you. Just create a .bat file with the following contents:

```
REG ADD HKLM\System\CUrrentControlSet\Services\SeleniumRC\Parameters /v Application /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"

REG ADD HKLM\System\CUrrentControlSet\Services\SeleniumRC\Parameters /v AppDirectory /t REG_SZ /d "%CD%"

REG ADD HKLM\System\CUrrentControlSet\Services\SeleniumRC\Parameters /v AppParameters /t REG_SZ /d "-Xrs -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar"
```

(thanks @jscott for the tip)

Comment: You may want to consider double-quotes around `%CD%`, should it contain a space.

Comment: Agreed - edited to reflect that